# Copying file with special characters from USB in SSH

Tags: pi-3, usb

I'm trying to copy a file with () in it.

Example:  Super Mario World (USA).srm

I've tried: `cp /media/usb/Super-Mario-World-"(USA)".srm`
and many others and I can't seem to find an answer on the web.

Comment: Try the quotes around the entire path and file name like this cp "/media/usb/Super-Mario-World-(USA).srm" not just around the quotes. Though the better solution would be to rename the file and remove the parens.

Answer (score 1):

The spaces are a problem here as well.

> Example: Super Mario World (USA).srm

If it doesn't contain quotes of its own, you can just quote it:

```
cp 'Super Mario World (USA).srm'
```

Double or single are equivalent in this case (for the fine print [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697781/1151724)).  You can also use escapes on the spaces and parantheses, which is more awkward when there's a lot of them:

```
cp Super\ Mario\ World\ \(USA\).srm
```